# Jenkins DSL booleanCondition() not returning true even if true is passed

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have two jobs called `ParentJob` and `ChildJob`. `ParentJob` triggers the downstream job `ChildJob`.

From `ParentJob` i am passing the variable as

```
parameters {
            predefinedProp('RELEASE','true')  
           }
```

In the `ChildJob` i am picking the parameter as

```
conditionalSteps {
      condition {
        booleanCondition("RELEASE")
        steps {
          shell("echo 'Wow !!! condition is parsed as true'")
        }
      }
```

In the `ChildJob`'s parameter page, I can see it coming correctly as `true`:

[image]

Still the line `shell("echo 'Wow !!! condition is parsed as true'")` is not executing. In the logs, I can see :

```
09:35:41 Run condition [Boolean condition] enabling prebuild for step [BuilderChain]
09:35:41 [Boolean condition] checking [RELEASE] against [^(1|y|yes|t|true|on|run)$] (origin token: RELEASE)
09:35:41 Run condition [Boolean condition] preventing perform for step [BuilderChain]
09:35:41 Finished: SUCCESS
```

I even tried passing as `false` from `ParentJob` job, still the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was wrongly accessing the token,where the correct way is `booleanCondition('${RELEASE}')`.

This should be the proper way :

```
conditionalSteps {
      condition {
        booleanCondition('${RELEASE}')
        steps {
          shell("echo 'Wow !!! condition is parsed as true'")
        }
      }
    }
```